# Set transparency to a control in windows form

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2015

I am new in programming. I can’t find a way to set transparency to a control. Please help. Something like, `Form.transparency` or some thing else.

Comment: What you need is `SetStyle` and `BackColor` `Color.Transparent`

Comment: This is too duplicate to mention!

Comment: Do you even google? Bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple way to make a form transparent is just to set the `Form.Opacity` property to a value. 
Or, you can try, **API** calls for doing that,

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetLayeredWindowAttributes(IntPtr hwnd, uint crKey, byte bAlpha, uint dwFlags);
public const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
public const int WS_EX_LAYERED = 0x80000;
public const int LWA_ALPHA = 0x2;
public const int LWA_COLORKEY = 0x1;
```

For Calling,

```
SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) ^ WS_EX_LAYERED);
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(Handle, 0, 128, LWA_ALPHA);
```

Comment: It works. But, I can't set `Opacity` to any specific control in the form

Comment: Windows does not support a control to be transparent. But, you can try, `Form.TransparencyKey` to a `System.Drawing.Color` which will eventually make that `Color` always transparent irrespective of where it is.